# Place page title over image

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I want to place an *image* at the top of the content `<div>` tag in a custom Joomla site, then place the *page title* over the top of the image. The site is currently being developed locally so I don't have any links sorry. The rest of the site is coming along pretty smoothly, any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making this harder than it needs to be. First, you can add the image in the header by simply adding a module position (if there isn't one already) within your header div. Next, I am assuming you are talking about the title of a Joomla article. This can easily be displayed in the component area then moved using CSS. You already gave a container div (content). As long as you don't specify the position attribute of the divs between content and your page title, you will be able to position your title absolutely anywhere within the content div, including over the top of the image you added to the header in a module.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make changes to your `index.php` of your template.

Add a div above the `<div class="container">` then you can make a db call using `JFactory::getDBO()` and fetch data you want and show it in the div.

```
<div class="page-name"></div>
<div class="custom_div"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<!-- rest of the index.php divs goes here -->
```

if you want the specific div only in the front page, use the below code.

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
        echo '<div></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't quite understand tho, could you explain a bit more. Here is the code from my template that I have built. 

    <div class="content"> 
    <div class="header"> 
    /* Image display at the top of div*/ 
    <div class="page-name"> 
    /* Title of the article goes here, through css it will sit over the image*/ 
    </div> 
    </div> 
    <jdoc:include type="component" /> 
    </div>

I'm unsure how to get the image to sit within the header div and call the title of the article.

Comment: answer updated. ask if you don't get it